# Scrollbar for usercontrol inside tab panel - winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, autoscroll, tablelayoutpanel

I have looked and looked, and while I've found many similar questions, none of them seem to be addressing my particular problem, so I thought I'd just go ahead and start a new one.

I have a dialog whose primary control is a tab panel. One of these tabs will be containing a user control.

That custom user control is an "accordian". It contains a table layout panel set up so that each even row has a button that will grow and shrink the row underneath it. This is done by setting autosize=true on the odd rows and changing the size of the odd row contents in the button click event. For the purposes of this question, the important part is that the table grows and shrinks at run-time due to user input, not just during initial layout.

My problem is that I can't get a vertical scrollbar to appear when (and only when) the accordian is too large for the dialog. I don't care which level of the heirarchy this scroll bar is attached to, as long as it scrolls the accordian. 
The heierarchy is: tabPanelAccordian->AccordianUC1->tablelayoutPanel1. I'm willing to insert a panel into the hierarchy if that's what's needed to get the scroll bar to work.

My current settings DON'T work, so I won't bother to include them here. I've played around with setting AutoSize, AutoScroll, Docking and Anchors on all the levels, but haven't found the right combo yet. On the advice from another thread, I've included the following line in all events that change accordian height:

```
  tableLayoutPanel1.AutoScrollMinSize = tableLayoutPanel1.GetPreferredSize(new Size(1, 1));
```

Although I don't think I've included this line in all the different permutations. Nothing seems to get the scrollbar to appear only when the accordian is too big. I'm hoping for advice on how to do this.

Thanks!

Comment: Set the TabPage to AutoScroll.